# AngularJS - function never gets control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete, angularjs-scope

First of all, I really hope for everyone's understanding and tolerance. This question is quite specific, so please no more radicalism, down-voting, putting on hold or abuse. We are all here to learn something new and share knowledge, not aggression. Many thanks.

The question: I am trying to follow [this example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) but function newState does not seem to get control while it works in [the link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete). Can anyone tell exactly why this does not happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

          angular
              .module('myapp', ['ngMaterial'])
              .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

          function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q, $log) {
            var self = this;
            self.simulateQuery = false;
            self.isDisabled    = false;
            // list of `state` value/display objects
            self.states        = loadAll();
            self.querySearch   = querySearch;
            self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
            self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
            self.newState = newState;
            function newState(state) {
              alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constituion for " + state + " first!");
            }
            // ******************************
            // Internal methods
            // ******************************
            /**
             * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
             * remote dataservice call.
             */
            function querySearch (query) {
              var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
                  deferred;
              if (self.simulateQuery) {
                deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                return deferred.promise;
              } else {
                return results;
              }
            }
            function searchTextChange(text) {
              $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
            }
            function selectedItemChange(item) {
              $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
            }
            /**
             * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
             */
            function loadAll() {
              var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                      Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                      Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                      Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                      North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                      South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                      Wisconsin, Wyoming';
              return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
                return {
                  value: state.toLowerCase(),
                  display: state
                };
              });
            }
            /**
             * Create filter function for a query string
             */
            function createFilterFor(query) {
              var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
              return function filterFn(state) {
                return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
              };
            }
          }

    </script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
          <p>Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.</p>
          <md-autocomplete
              ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
              md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
              md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
              md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
              md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
              md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
              md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
              md-item-text="item.display"
              md-min-length="0"
              placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
            <md-item-template>
              <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>
              No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
              <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
            </md-not-found>
          </md-autocomplete>
          <br/>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.simulateQuery">Simulate query for results?</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.noCache">Disable caching of queries?</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.isDisabled">Disable the input?</md-checkbox>
          <p>By default, <code>md-autocomplete</code> will cache results when performing a query.  After the initial call is performed, it will use the cached results to eliminate unnecessary server requests or lookup logic. This can be disabled above.</p>
        </form>
      </md-content>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have an easier time getting an answer if you can distill this down to the bare essentials to reproduce the issue. You might even figure it out yourself. Please remove the cruft.

Comment: That is a minimal sample I am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, not entirely sure WHAT the issue is but simply updating the Angular Material version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.6 seemed to fix it for me. Though now I'm getting some exceptions about $apply already in progress.
EDIT: $apply already in progress seems to only occur on Firefox, chrome was just fine.

Comment: Many thanks. Let me ask you a question how stable AngularJS is? To me is feels like walking on eggs at the moment. Is my perception correct?

Comment: I can't attest for Angular Material, but AngularJS has been quite stable for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed [here](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/52a519ead04f2faeba227fbc51a7214253cbf2ba).
It's ok from v1.0.5.

You can click the 'Edit On Codepen' icon on the [example page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) you provided and change the angular-material version on Codepen to verify.